# Nginx not accessing static files on server

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to serve static files (like .css .pdf .jpg) on Nginx but I'm getting the 403 forbidden error so the page layout is broken and files are not accessible. For example, I'm not able to access the style.css file if I navigate to that file directly.

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/configfile

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name ipaddress here;

        location /static {
                alias /home/username/webapp/static;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

home directory permission:

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Jul 30 05:45 home
```

user directory permission:

```
drwxr-x--- 6 username username 4096 Jul 30 06:17 username
```

webapp directory permission:

```
drwxrwxr-x 7 username username 4096 Jul 30 15:57 webapp
```

webapp/static/ directory permission:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 username username 4096 Jul 30 06:04 static
```

webapp/static/style.css permission:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username  24672 Jul 30 06:04 style.css
```

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There are four directories in `/home/username/webapp/static`, the process running Nginx needs read access to all of them.

Comment: @RichardSmith I pasted the permissions above, it seems Nginx does have read access to all of them.

Comment: Unless Nginx is running as the user `usename` - it will not have access to the `/home/username` folder.

Comment: @RichardSmith I'm still learning about this.  so do I change "user www-data;" to "user username;"? What else do I need to edit? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wish Chairman Meow have already solved the issue. I just share my idea to help the others who jumped into this post (and hopefully Chairman Meow).
I am not English-native speaker, so please forgive my poor English.

First of all, I suppose Nginx had been installed by using a packge manager such as **apt** on Ubuntu/Debian or **yum** on RedHat/CentOS, etc. because `/var/log` and `/etc/nginx` folders are generally default configuration from package-manager-installed nginx. In addition, I also suppose Chairman Meow is the **sudoer**.

Basically, my idea is about the permission requried for nginx worker process and some security concern.

In `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, 'user **www-data**' directive is used, which means nginx worker process runs as with the privilege of account **www-data**. (normally nginx master process runs as the root's process. ref: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/basic-functionality/runtime-control/ )

In the original `nginx.conf`,however like Richard Smith wrote, there is a permission problem. `/home/username`(drwxr-x---) directory cannot be accessed by others including user 'www-data'. So Nginx worker process can't handle the request to the route /static (which points `/home/username/webapp/static` directory)

One solution might be to change 'user **www-data**' to 'user **username**'. But I think this is usually not recommended, if 'username' is the user account for real user. That is because it is not safe to open the access to someone's home directory from the view point of security.

My suggestion is, if the content under `/static` path is not necessarily stored under `/home/username` directory, to move the static content to other directory for web contents such as `/var/www/html` or to a newly created one.

For example,

1. create static content directory, and change owner for that.

   sudo mkdir */var/www/webapp*
2. move files from the previous directory to the new one

   sudo mv */home/username/webapp/static* */var/www/web/app*
3. change owner and access permission

   sudo chown -R root:root */var/www/webapp*
   sudo chmod -R 775 */var/www/webapp*
4. Edit config file (plus, change the config file name for clarity)

   sudo mv */etc/nginx/sites-enabled/configfile* */etc/nginx/sites-enabled/webapp-config*

In */etc/nginx/sites-enabled/webapp-config* (also touched *server_name* directive)

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name _;

        location /static {
                alias /var/www/webapp/static;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```